# htaccess seo-friendly URL's

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, seo, friendly-url

I need some help to get friendly URL's on my website.

These are my links i need to rewrite:

```
www.example.com/index.php?page=pagename
www.example.com/index.php?page=profile&id=number
```

This is my .htaccess. I solved the issue for the first link, however I can't do it for the second one.

I would like to have for the second link:

```
www.example.com/profile/name or
www.example.com/profile/id
```

This is my .htaccess file:

```
# for www.example.com/index.php?page=profile&id=number
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?page=([^&]+)&id=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [L,R=301]

# for www.example.com/index.php?page=page
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?page=([^&\ ]+)($|\ )
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [L,R=301]

# rewrites back
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([0-9]+)$ /index.php?page=$1&id=$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

The code I submitted above solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
# for www.example.com/index.php?page=profile&id=number
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} page=([^&]+)&id=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [L,R=301]

# for www.example.com/index.php?page=page
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} page=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [L,R=301]
```

And for rewrites back

```
# rewrites back
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([0-9]+)$ /index.php?page=$1&id=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Comment: I got this link after I added your code: http://example.com/profile/206?page=profile&id=206

Comment: Now both of links doesn't work: The page isn't redirecting properly

Comment: I change almost nothing... :-(

Comment: Looks like my initial code I submitted works now, lol. I got the /profile/id friendly url.

Comment: `QSD` is available from Apache 2.4 and later https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsd

Comment: @hjpotter92 yes, you're right. In this case, we just can add `?` after `%2` or `%1` in RewriteRules